# AWS: DB Instance quota exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

During CloudFormation stack-creation I get a `CREATE_FAILED` error for Aurora with reason `DB Instance quota exceeded`.

I assume it means there are too many DB instances running (I'm on a company account with a federated login, and not the only one creating stacks and launching instances).

How do I fix it? Do need to delete some running instances? Also, how do I find out what the allowed quota is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Limits in Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html) shows a limit of 40 Amazon RDS DB Instances per Region.

You can contact AWS Customer Service to request a limit increase. Here's the Support screen:

[image: RDS Limit increase]